# CoffeeScript ng-show being applied for all elements in list

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I have a list of elements rendered with 
`%ul{ :"ng-repeat" => "cospace in cospaces" }`

Inside of each `li` I have an element that loads another `div` with `{ 'ng-mouseover' => "loadSubAttr(cospace.id, 'is_in_wishlist')"}`

I want that other div to display when a condition is met and that works perfectly with this code `{ :'ng-show' => "nb_copassers > 0" }`

The problem is that it toggles the display of the `div` inside the `li` for each `li`.
For example, I hover over an item and if my condition is met, all `li`s will display the `div`. How do I make the `ng-show` local to each `li`? Or is there a better way of doing this all together? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `nb_copassers > 0` as the `ng-show` expression, you probably want to use a value that is related to the "cospace" that `ng-repeat` is currently iterating through. For instance:

```
{ :'ng-show' => "cospace.nb_copassers > 0" }
```

If you don't have a value of `nb_copassers` for each cospace, you won't be able to decide which one you'll display the `div` for! Or maybe there's another criteria for deciding which element should display the `div`, but you don't mention that in your question so I assume there isn't. If there is, update your question and I'll adjust this answer.

Comment: That did it. I wasn't sure how to associate or "nest" the copasser model into the cospace model in the json but I figured out how to concatenate the two. Thanks for the help!